# Enforcing multi-tenant security on SQL mapping table - JPA, Hibernate, Spring

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Our DB contains 2 tables, `task` and `user` which are joined by a many to many mapping table, `task_assignee`. Both tables include an **account_id** field which indicates the tenant.

`task_assignee` contains 2 columns, 'task_id' and 'user_id', which are FK's to `task.id` and `user.id`.

Using JPA, I model the join as follows:

```
public class Task {
        ...

        @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(
        name = "task_assignee", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "task_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }
    )
    List<User> assignedUsers;
}
```

I accomplish multitenant security on API write operations of *top level* records such as `task` by setting the records 'accountId' to the authenticated callers account prior to DAO, and rejecting any API request in which 'accountId' was included. For read operations, we apply a session filter such that any query includes a `WHERE account_id = {authenticated user account}`. For example:

```
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Filter filter = session.enableFilter("account_id");
    filter.setParameter("account_id", 123);
```

However, this does not block an API user from adding `users` to a `task` that **do not belong to the account**.

Short of adding a query to check that a `user` belongs to an `account` before adding as an assignee, can JPA handle this with a filter?

Comment: Have you checked the multitenancy support of Hibernate? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-discriminator

Comment: Thanks. If I were to use this, I'd require discriminator implementation which doesn't appear to be available yet.